# how to draw a surface using lispbuilder

Tags: common-lisp

I want to draw a surface using [lispbuilder](http://code.google.com/p/lispbuilder/wiki/UsingLispbuilderSDL#User_Events), but I am not able to convert the user-guide/api into a working example.

This is what I currently have:

```
(defun func (version)
  (sdl:with-init ()
    (sdl:window 1023 768 :title-caption "Move a rectangle using the mouse")
    (setf (sdl:frame-rate) 60)
    (setf *map-surface* (sdl:load-image "...src/resources/map.jpg"))
    (sdl:with-events ()
      (:quit-event () t)
      (:key-down-event ()
               (sdl:push-quit-event))
      (:idle ()
         (sdl:draw-surface *map-surface*) 

         ;; Change the color of the box if the left mouse button is depressed
         (when (sdl:mouse-left-p)
           (setf *random-color* (sdl:color :r (random 255) :g (random 255) :b (random 255))))

          ;; Clear the display each game loop
          (sdl:clear-display sdl:*black*)

          ;; Draw the box having a center at the mouse x/y coordinates.
          (sdl:draw-box (sdl:rectangle-from-midpoint-* (sdl:mouse-x) (sdl:mouse-y) 20 20)
                 :color *random-color*)

          ;; Redraw the display
          (sdl:update-display))))))
```

But it does not draw the surface at all. I already checked whether the surface is loaded successfully. I would also appreciate a recommendation to a tutorial/paper covering that library, as the actual "user guide" is not really for starter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, everything works. But as you redraw the screen every time (`(sdl:clear-display sdl:*black*)`), you don't get to see the picture. Try commenting out this line...